# How does a Ruby method handle an object for a parameter?

Tags: ruby

Say you have a Date class in java with this constructor:

```
public Date(int year, int month, int day)
```

and in this class you have a method that returns the number of days that this `Date` must be
adjusted to make it equal to the given `Date`:

```
public int daysTo(Date other)
```

If you were to recreate this class in Ruby how would you handle this `daysTo` method?

Comment: Subtraction? What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? There's nothing really special that would need to be done here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyDate
  attr_reader :days

  def initialize(days_since_epoch)
    @days = days_since_epoch
  end

  def days_to(other)
    other.days - days
  end
end

date1 = MyDate.new 100
date2 = MyDate.new 150
date1.days_to(date2) #=> 50
```